# Macbook Pro Xcode Uninstall sedo .h files still there

Tags: finder, xcode

I recently unistalled Xcode using Sedo developer in the terminal.  The reason I uninstalled is because every time I searched for something in finder, millions of .h and .m files would show and crowd my search.  After deleting as much Xcode files and folders as possible the .m, .h, & .c files are still showing in my finder window when searching.  They are a different color now but still there.  I want to delete them badly, I just don't think I should, but I desperately would like them to not appear in my searches.  I don't understand why I still have the .h files after uninstalling Xcode.  Please help

Answer (score 1):

May I propose two other options

- Remove the "Developer" category from Spotlight search results (in Spotlight Preferences)

[image]

- Add `/usr/include` to the exclusion list (click '+' and then <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> to enter the path)